# Why methods of moments is not widely used in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, inference, method-of-moments

If I recall correctly, in most machine learning context I have encountered, only maximum likelihood estimation and maximum a posteriori method are used. Why not method of moments?

Comment: You can refer to [Advantages of method of moments estimators
(mmes)](https://www.liquisearch.com/method_of_moments_statistics/advantages_and_disadvantages_of_this_method) and [Method of Moments (statistics) - Advantages and Disadvantages of This Method](https://www.liquisearch.com/method_of_moments_statistics/advantages_and_disadvantages_of_this_method).